# PHP integer value in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here `$id` is integer value and it's not deleting from MySQL:

```
$Query="DELETE FROM table WHERE id='.$id.' and cid='".$cid."'";
```

Comment: OMG, SQL INJECTIONS - WELCOME!!!! 
PLEASE, use [mysqli](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with prepared statements.

Comment: $Query="DELETE FROM table WHERE id=".mysql_real_scape_string($id)." and cid=".mysql_real_scape_string($cid)."";

Comment: I see two statements, and then a line of code. Not sure what to do with this...

Comment: @RobertRozas `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't much better, he should switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also, how do you know he wasn't / isn't using `mysql_real_escape_string` somewhere *before* the line he posted?

Comment: Yes i know....but just seeing the way he is making the query, i realize he is using mysql extension...anyway, it was just a comment, not a full answer ;)

Comment: You can also cast the variable as an integer rather than using `mysqli->real_escape_string` (or `mysql_real_escape_string`). Strings will be evaluated as `0`: `"DELETE FROM table WHERE id=" . (integer)$id ...`. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your `"`

## The Solution:

```
$id = mysql_real_scape_string($id);
$cid = mysql_real_scape_string($cid);

$Query="DELETE FROM table WHERE id='".$id."' and cid='".$cid."'";
```

**The Problem**

So, if you were to `echo` out your statement as it was, the result would look like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id='.1.' and cid='2'
```

See the problem with that?

Comment: What about `$cid`, wouldn't you escape that as well?

Comment: @Jasper Yes you would, I made a mistake and have since fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem in short: **you have mixed different quotation marks - `"` and `'`**.

This problem would not arise if you would use ***prepared statements***, as you would have had a single string literal:

```
$Query="DELETE FROM table WHERE id=? and cid=?";
```

This would also remove the possibility of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This would also **speed-up** you program if you need to execute the same prepared statement several times (the statement is already *prepared* and does not need to be *parsed* on the second+ invocation).

And finally, in case you are still using the [*officially deprecated* PHP **mysql** extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) you **MUST** switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and use its full benefits like prepared statements. The mysql extension *is no longer officially supported and may be removed in future* (though I foresee that it will be moved to PEAR or so).

---

As a temporary solution, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to encode **all** variables which are derived from the user input. Please do **NOT** use `mysql_escape_string` as it is highly vulnerable to character encoding!